# Inter rater agreement where categories are not predetermined

Tags: agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

How can I measure inter-rater agreement, e.g., using the Kappa coefficient, during an exploratory study where the categories are not predetermined?

Comment: Could you provide more information on your setup? Are raters going to freely assess some subjects or topics, like if "categories" were open-ended questions?

Comment: @chi That's correct. It is ultimately open-ended.

Comment: Any way to recode the open-ended answers? I f so you could end up with a fixed number of categories, which could be handled with inter-agreement methods after you discard the less frequent ones.

Comment: I guess we could do a pilot study (e.g., 5%) to come up with a fixed number of categories.

Comment: Sure, that would be great. Otherwise I don't see how you could possibly use Cohen's kappa or any other measure of agreement if the number of items is not fixed.